# Simple Geometric problem

Tags: code-golf, geometry

[This problem](http://hs10.spoj.pl/problems/HS10RECT/) (see below) has been given as a High School Programming League code golf challenge. The shortest codes submitted during the contest were: 177 bytes in Ruby, 212 bytes in Python 2.5, 265 bytes in C. Can anyone make it shorter? Other programming languages are also allowed.

**Problem formulation**: Given 8 integers: -1000 < x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 < 1000. Check what is the shape of the intersection of two axis-aligned rectangles: P1 = (x1, y1), (x1, y2), (x2, y2), (x2, y1) and P2 = (x3, y3), (x3, y4), (x4, y4), (x4, y3).

```
* If the rectangles do not intersect print *nothing*.
* If there is exactly one point in common print *point*.
* If the intersections of P1 and P2 is a line segment print *line*.
* If they have a rectangular area in common print *rectangle*.
```

**Input data specification**: The first line contains the number of test cases *t* (1<=*t*<1000). Each of the following t lines contains 8 integers: x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 (The area of both rectangles is greater than 0).

You can test your solution [here](http://www.spoj.pl/HSPLARCH/problems/HS10RECT/).

Comment: How come I don't see any submitted solutions to this problem?

Comment: @Keith Randall  The contest session is over, results for submitted solutions are summarized [here](https://hs.spoj.pl/ranks/HS10RECT/)

Comment: What if the coordinates don't make rectangles? What if the shapes overlap to form a shape other than a rectangle?

Comment: @J843136028 you can assume that they do form a rectangle. To the second part off the question  I can see now that it is not mentioned that rectangles are axis-aligned (missing word added).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Python, 200 characters

```
f=lambda a,b,c,d:min(2,sum((x-c)*(x-d)<=0for x in range(min(a,b),max(a,b)+1)))
for i in' '*input():z=map(int,raw_input().split());print('nothing','point','line',0,'rectangle')[f(*z[::2])*f(*z[1::2])]
```

`f` returns:

```
0 if the intervals [a,b] and [c,d] don't overlap
1 if the intervals [a,b] and [c,d] overlap in only one point
2 if the intervals [a,b] and [c,d] overlap in a range of points
```

Answer (score 3):

**OCaml, 265 chars**

```
let a,c,p=abs,compare,print_endline
let q s t u v w x y z=match
c(a(s-u)+a(w-y))(a(s+u-w-y)),
c(a(t-v)+a(x-z))(a(t+v-x-z))with
0,0->p"point"|0,1|1,0->p"line"|1,1->p"rectangle"|_->p"nothing"
let()=for n=1 to read_int()do Scanf.scanf"%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n"q done
```

Uses (abuses) the fact that compare returns 0, 1 or -1. This is not guaranteed according to its documentation but true with OCaml 3.10.1.

Comment: Nice! One suggestion:I would write Scanf.scanf" %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d" (-1 char)