# Generate Pascal's triangle

Tags: code-golf, math, combinatorics

[Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) is generated by starting with a 1 on the first row. On subsequent rows, the number is determined by the sum of the two numbers directly above it to the left and right.

To demonstrate, here are the first 5 rows of Pascal's triangle:

```
    1
   1 1
  1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

### The Challenge

Given an input *n* (provided however is most convenient in your chosen language), generate the first *n* rows of Pascal's triangle. You may assume that *n* is an integer inclusively between 1 and 25. There must be a line break between each row and a space between each number, but aside from that, you may format it however you like.

This is **code-golf**, so the shortest solution wins.

### Example I/O

```
> 1
1
> 9
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
1 5 10 10 5 1
1 6 15 20 15 6 1
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
```

Comment: NB In a sense this is a simplified version of [Distributing the balls](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/code-golf-distributing-the-balls-i)

Comment: @Peter Olson: What's your opinion of ratchet freak's interpretation of "you may format it however you like"?  If I followed his interpretation I could shave 18 characters.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski He's fine. There's a newline between each row, and there is a space between each number, so it meets the criteria.

Comment: @Peter Olson:  Thanks for the clarification.  What about Tomas T's assumption that n is defined already?

Comment: @PeterOlson Will there ever be an accepted answer to this question?

Comment: @Gaffi Probably not, accepting an answer makes me feel like I'm ending the contest and discouraging new and possibly better answers.

Answer (score 35):

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 characters

```
":@(!{:)\@i.
```

---

```
   i.5
0 1 2 3 4
   {:i.5
4
   (i.5)!{:i.5
1 4 6 4 1
   (!{:)i.5
1 4 6 4 1
   (!{:)\i.5
1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
1 2 1 0 0
1 3 3 1 0
1 4 6 4 1
   ":@(!{:)\i.5
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
   (":@(!{:)\@i.)`''
+----------------------------------+
|+-+------------------------------+|
||@|+-------------------------+--+||
|| ||+-+---------------------+|i.|||
|| |||\|+-------------------+||  |||
|| ||| ||+-+---------------+|||  |||
|| ||| |||@|+--+----------+||||  |||
|| ||| ||| ||":|+-+------+|||||  |||
|| ||| ||| ||  ||2|+-+--+||||||  |||
|| ||| ||| ||  || ||!|{:|||||||  |||
|| ||| ||| ||  || |+-+--+||||||  |||
|| ||| ||| ||  |+-+------+|||||  |||
|| ||| ||| |+--+----------+||||  |||
|| ||| ||+-+---------------+|||  |||
|| ||| |+-------------------+||  |||
|| ||+-+---------------------+|  |||
|| |+-------------------------+--+||
|+-+------------------------------+|
+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: J beats GolfScript?  Interesting.  I would like to see an explanation for this code, if you have time.

Comment: It's already split down, but here's a line by line if you'd like additional english.  Line 1 `i.5` returns the first five naturals.    Line 2 adds `{:` "Tail" (return last).  Line 3 combines them with `!` "Out Of" (number of combinations).  Line 4 `(!{:)i.5` is the same. factoring the hook out.  So `(!:)` is an operation that transforms the first *n* naturals to the nth line of Pascal's triangle.  Line 5 applies it to all Prefixes (backslash) of 0..4, but J fills in the unused spots with 0, so the operation is combined (`@`) with the string formatting operation `":`.  Very cool J, upvoted.

Comment: @JB Isn't ! means factorial here? Also we can get rid of @ at the right.

Comment: @ArtemIce Monadic `!` means factorial; dyadic `!` counts combinations.  The final `@` in `":@(!{:)\@i.` is just there to make this a stand-alone verb.

Answer (score 24):

## Python, 56 Bytes

```
a=[1];exec"print a;a=map(sum,zip([0]+a,a+[0]));"*input()
```

Sample usage:

```
echo 9 | python filename.py
```

Produces:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
[1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
[1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1]
```

Comment: +1 Clever way to use `exec` avoid a `for` loop.

Answer (score 19):

## C, 522

A self demonstrating C answer. Couldn't be clearer!
Bonus points for finding the extra character.

```c
#define returns return 0
#define fr for
#define twentyonechexpressis0 0
                                                                                i
                                                                               , x
                                                                              [ 52 ]
                                                                            [ 52] ,j, y
                                                                       ; main (c){fr (;i< c
                                                                    ; i++){ x[i][i]=x[ i][0]= 1
                                                         ; }for(i =2;i<c;i++){for (j=1;j<i;j++){x [i][j] =
                                    1 +x[i][j ]+x[i-1][j-1]+x[i-1] [j]+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+111-11- twentyonechexpressis0 -100-1; }
} ;for(i=0 ;i<c;i++){for(j=0;j<=i;j++){ printf("%3d%c",x[i][j],(1+1+1+1)*(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)) ;}putchar(1+1+(1<<1+1)+1+1+1+1+1+111111-111111-1);} /*thiscomment_takes28chars*/ returns; }
```

Comment: I can't help but feel that this misses the point of code golf. (I also can't help pointing out that the extra character is in the \binom{5}{4} position).

Comment: It was fun to write. That's generally what I come to codegolf for.

Comment: Clever :) Have an upvote. Maybe not a winner candidate but a creative one!

Answer (score 16):

### Mathematica: 36 (41?)

Mathematica has the `Binomial` function, but that takes the fun out of this.  I propose:

```
NestList[{0,##}+{##,0}&@@#&,{1},n-1]
```

The line above will render a ragged array such as:

```
{{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 3, 1}, {1, 4, 6, 4, 1},
 {1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1}, {1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1}}
```

Since this is a basic format in Mathematica I thought it would be acceptable, but as I read the rules again, I think it may not be.  Adding `Grid@` will produce unequivocally acceptable output, for a total of **41** characters:

```
Grid@NestList[{0,##}+{##,0}&@@#&,{1},n-1]
```

`n = 6`:

```
1                       
1   1                   
1   2   1               
1   3   3   1           
1   4   6   4   1       
1   5   10  10  5   1   
1   6   15  20  15  6   1
```

Answer (score 16):

### Python, <strike>94</strike> <strike>91</strike> <strike>88</strike> <strike>70</strike> 63 characters

```
x=[1]
for i in input()*x:
 print x
 x=map(sum,zip([0]+x,x+[0]))
```

Answer (score 14):

#### Golfscript (21 chars)

```
~]({0\{.@+\}/;1].p}*;
```

Since an explanation was requested:

```
# Stack contains 'n'
~](
# Stack: [] n
{
    # prev_row is [\binom{i,0} ... \binom{i,i}]
    # We loop to generate almost all of the next row as
    #     [(\binom{i,-1} + \binom{i,0}) ... (\binom{i,i-1} + \binom{i,i})]
    # \binom{i,-1} is, of course, 0
    # Stack: prev_row
    0\
    # Stack: 0 prev_row
    {
        # Stack: ... \binom{i,j-1} \binom{i,j}
        .@+\
        # Stack: ... (\binom{i,j-1} + \binom{i,j}) \binom{i,j}
    }/
    # Stack: \binom{i+1,0} ... \binom{i+1,i} \binom{i,i}
    # unless it's the first time round, when we still have 0
    # so we need to pop and then push a 1 for \binom{i+1,i+1}
    ;1]
    # next_row
    .p
}*
# final_row
;
```

Comment: You might want to try http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?pascal+triangle

Comment: Could you please provide some pseudo-code or explanation?  I kind of understand what's going on, but I'm not entirely understanding the swapping part.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and excellent answer (+1), but I'm even more confused now.  The logic (process) isn't sitting right.

Comment: @MikeDtrick, there was a slight error in the explanation. There's also a subtle point which needed explaining, but which I'd missed because it's so long since I wrote the code.

Comment: Okay, it's starting to make sense.  My final question be does the printing and executing process work from the top down or the bottom up (1, 1 1, 1 2 1: top down, 1 2 1, 1 1, 1: bottom up)?

Comment: @MikeDtrick, top-down. The uncommented `.p` at the end of the loop prints the line that was just generated.

Answer (score 12):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 39 bytes

convey is a new 2d esolang I made. It is based on conveyor belts that move values around in a factory. `v<^>` are explicit belt directions, other connections are inferred, as each function has a fixed number of inputs and outputs. For example, `+` takes 2 values in and returns 1 value.

```
v<<<.~/.]
v>,v}"!{
"/&v}11
\v>+/^
$,^
_
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoidjw8PC5+Ly5dXG52Pix2fVwiIXtcblwiLyZ2fTExXG5cXHY+Ky9eXG4kLF5cbl8iLCJ2IjoxLCJpIjoiNCJ9)

[image: pascals triangle]

A row enters the main part from the top left. Two tiles in, the row gets `"` copied down and right. The right part prepends a `_`, which is a so called 'default value'. The actual value of `_` depends on the function it enters. It works like the neutral element, thus `_ + 3 = 3`, `4 * _ = 4`.

To understand the next part we have to take a look at port order. For example, `,` will join two paths, favoring the main input port. The order is as follows (lower takes precedence):

```
For input:     For output:

   0                3
   v                ^
 1>f<3            2<f>0
   ^                v
   2                1
```

So the upper `,` will favor inputs from the left, and the lower `,` will favor inputs from the top. In the animation the arrow heads are drawn a bit thicker to indicate main ports.

On `/` (rising flank) whenever a new list enters the tile, `_` gets pushed to the side port. `_` and the row then get joined, whereas the `_` comes from the main port and thus has right of way.
The bottom part appends a `_` by similar means: `\` (falling flank) pushes the length of the list to the side port, that will be set `$` to `_`.

Finally, `_ 1 2 1` and `1 2 1 _` get added in `+` and we get the next row `1 3 3 1`! We print a newline `/}` (`_` in `}` prints newlines) and then copy the row into the output `"}`. To prevent a row colliding with the next row when they get longer, we batch `~.` the lists: we first let 1 element through, then 2, then 3 … by getting the indices `/.` of an list of `n` 1s (`{!1`}), that get discarded in a sink `]`.

Comment: unrelated question: how did you get the λ.land domain?

Comment: @Razetime most generic TLDs support non-latin letters/IDNs which are rarely taken because realistically you have to use the puny code variant (xn--wxa.land) most of the time. My more fun domain ꙮ.world f.e. lies in the extended Cyrillic UTF-8 block.

Answer (score 10):

## Ruby: <s>51</s> <s>49</s> 46 characters

(45 characters code + 1 character command line option)

```ruby
p=[];$_.to_i.times{n=0;p p.map!{|i|n+n=i}<<1}
```

Thanks to:

- [jsvnm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3586/jsvnm) for suggesting an alternative for the value switching (2 characters)
- [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18535/g-b) for spotting out a  variable unused after previous improvement (4 characters)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ ruby -ne 'p=[];$_.to_i.times{n=0;p p.map!{|i|n+n=i}<<1}' <<< 1
[1]

bash-4.4$ ruby -ne 'p=[];$_.to_i.times{n=0;p p.map!{|i|n+n=i}<<1}' <<< 9
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
[1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
[1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8A2OtZaJV6vJD8@U68kMze1uDrP1sC6QKFALzexQLG6JrMmTzvPNrPWxsaw9v9/y3/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzAA)

Comment: you can save 2 chars with `p.map!{|i|(v=n)+n=i}`

Comment: Great one, @jsvnm! Man, how long I combined to shorten that part. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a little late, but: why use the variable v?

Comment: Good catch, @GB! That left behind from [1st revision](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/5938/1), where… where… doh. Where was also kind of useless. I guess it comes from an earlier attempt when used `.map`. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

### Scala, <s>81</s> <s>78</s> <s>72</s> 70 characters

81 chars: first attempt, shamelessly copied from the Python version :)

```
var x=Seq(1)
for(i<-1 to args(0).toInt){println(x)
x=(0+:x,x:+0).zipped.map(_+_)}
```

Run it as a script, or directly in the REPL.

Cut to 70 chars with something surprisingly readable and idiomatic:

```
Seq.iterate(Seq(1),readInt)(a=>(0+:a,a:+0).zipped.map(_+_))map println
```

Or <s>72</s> 70 characters with a totally different method:

```
0 to(readInt-1)map(i=>println(0 to i map(1 to i combinations(_)size)))
```

Comment: + 1 for shameless copying!

Comment: The last version should be used carefully for huge values of readInt, like 50. ;)

Comment: @userunknown presumably that's why the question specifies an upper limit of 25...

Comment: It wasn't meant as critique, just as a warning for the curious.

Answer (score 9):

## [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg), <s>40</s> 33 bytes

```
1:&¿1.
,(|(⑻|:⑻$@MCƒℤ. ,⑨)⑹_01.
,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f0Ert0H5DPS4djRqNRxN311gBCRUHX@djkx61LNFT0Hk0cYXmo4k74w1Aav7/twAA)

### Old Program Explained

[image: Pen]
[image: Highlighted]

Answer (score 8):

## Haskell, <s>94</s> 92

```
f=[1]:[zipWith(+)(0:x)x++[1]|x<-f]
main=readLn>>=mapM_(putStrLn.unwords.map show).(`take`f)
```

Output:

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

A 71 character version which does not print a space between each number:

```
f=[1]:[zipWith(+)(0:x)x++[1]|x<-f]
main=readLn>>=mapM_ print.(`take`f)
```

Output:

```
[1]
[1,1]
[1,2,1]
[1,3,3,1]
```

Comment: You can save a character by using `mapM` instead of `mapM_`.

Answer (score 7):

## R, 39 chars

R seems to be the very right tool for this task :-)

```
x=1;for(i in 1:n)x=c(print(x),0)+c(0,x)
```

Comment: You're missing one of the requirements: "Given an input n (provided however is most convenient in your chosen language)"

Comment: @Steven, "Given an input n"... so may I assume the `n` is given? I corrected the code. Is this now OK?

Comment: I'm asked Peter Olson to clarify.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I don't think that's valid unless it takes input. I don't know R, so maybe the compiler makes it so that undefined variables prompt an input, so it might be ok, but if it's like most other languages in that regard, I don't think it is.

Comment: @PeterOlson, so you require to read it from console? That's clumsy and it spoils the solutions... then I would have to use `scan()` instead of `n` and have 5 characters more... Please confirm and I'll modify my solution.

Comment: @TomasT. I don't care how you get the input, as long is `n` is provided by input somehow.

Comment: @PeterOlson, what does it mean "provided by input"?

Comment: Basically, the `n` must be supplied from an external source at run time and the apparatus for capturing it is included in your program.  Typically, that means by command line argument, or stdin, or file.  By file is almost never used because it's invariably longer than the other two options.

Answer (score 7):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [Zgarb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32014)*

```
mw↑¡Sż+Θ;1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P7f8UdvEQwuDj@7RPjfD2vD///@mAA)

#### Explanation

Based on the same idea as [my Pip answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211994/16766): generate each row from the last one by tacking a 0 to the front of the row and adding it to itself element-wise. The Husk version creates the entire triangle as an infinite lazy list and then takes however many rows we need.

```
        ;1  Start with [1]
   ¡        Iterate this function:
    S        S-combinator: Sfgx is fx(gx) (aka f(x,g(x)) in C-style syntax)
     ż+       f: add a list itemwise to another list, keeping the extra value at 
               the end of the longer list unchanged
       Θ      g: prepend a falsey value (given a list of integers, prepend 0)
             The result of Sż+Θ is a 1-argument function that prepends a 0 to its
              argument and adds that itemwise to another copy of the argument
  ↑         From the infinite list of results, take N (where N is the input)
mw          Join each sublist on spaces (which means the main list gets
             autojoined on newlines)
```

Comment: Nice first Husk answer! A couple of hints. `Θ` prepends a default falsy value, which is 0 for the number type. You can avoid creating a helper function with `S`. `Sfg` is equivalent to calling `fg¹` from a separate line.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (<strike>90</strike> <strike>85</strike> <strike>83</strike> 81)

```
for(n=prompt(o=i='');i++<n;o+='\n')for(s=j=1;j<=i;s=s*(i-j)/j++)o+=s+' ';alert(o)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tcRCS/3/

**NOTE**: Doesn't work well in practice for about n > 30 because numbers overflow built-in integer data type and become floating-point numbers.

---

**Edit 1**: removed 5 characters by converting `while` to `for` and combining statements

**Edit 2**: move `s=` statement inside `for` and save 2 chars

**Edit 3**: combine `s=1,j=1` initializer into `s=j=1` and save 2 chars

Comment: Nice!  You can save one more character by changing "s=s*..." to "s*=..."

Comment: @DerekKurth: I had thought that when I was first doing optimizations, but that would mess up the logic because it needs to be `s*(i-j)/j`, not `s*((i-j)/j)`.

Comment: Hmm, I tried it as s*=... in the jsfiddle and it seemed to work.  Maybe I did something wrong, though.

Comment: @DerekKurth: Technically it is the same, but the idea is that if you multiply by `(i-j)` before dividing by `j`, then there is no need for floating point arithmetic because the results should always be an integer.  If you do `((i-j)/j)` first, this will result in decimal values which can be a source of error, and at the very least will require extra code for rounding/truncating.  You don't begin to see this until you get to about `n>11`, and you'll see decimal values in the output, i.e., `1 11 55 165 330 461.99999999999994 461.99999999999994...`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!

Answer (score 6):

### Perl, <strike>52</strike>, 49 characters

Edit: using `say` instead of `print`

```
map{@_=(1,map$_[$_-1]+$_[$_],1..@_);say"@_"}1..<>
```

Answer (score 6):

### in Q (25 characters/20 with shorter version)

```
t:{(x-1) (p:{0+':x,0})\1}
```

Shorter

```
t:{(x-1){0+':x,0}\1}
```

Sample usage:

```
q)t 4
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
```

Comment: Or alternatively, 20 characters `t:{(x-1){0+':x,0}\1}`

Comment: Nice, shorter than the GolfScript solution now.

Answer (score 6):

## awk - 73 chars

fairly straightforward implementation:

```
{for(i=0;i<$1;++i)for(j=i;j>=0;)printf"%d%c",Y[j]+=i?Y[j-1]:1,j--?32:10}
```

sample run:

```
% awk -f pascal.awk <<<10
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
1 5 10 10 5 1
1 6 15 20 15 6 1
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
```

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, <s>47</s> 54 characters

```perl
$p=1;map{print"@{[split//,$p]}\n";$p*=11}1..<>
```

It takes a number from the command line, but doesn't perform any error checks.

Just realized it only works up to n=4. It was some old code I had on my hd.

This works though:

```perl
map{@a=(1,map$a[$_-1]+=$a[$_],1..@a);print"@a\n"}a..n
```

n has to be input into the script though, or it would be one character more.

Answer (score 5):

## Pascal: <s>216</s> 192 characters

(Not a real competitor, just an honorific presence.)

```pascal
var p:array[0..1,0..25]of LongInt;i,j,n,u:Word;begin
Read(n);u:=0;for i:=1to n do begin
p[1,1]:=1;for j:=1to i do begin
p[u,j]:=p[1-u,j-1]+p[1-u,j];Write(p[u,j],' ')end;u:=1-u;Writeln
end
end.
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ fpc pascal.pas 
/usr/bin/ld: warning: link.res contains output sections; did you forget -T?

bash-4.2$ ./pascal <<< 1
1 

bash-4.2$ ./pascal <<< 9
1 
1 1 
1 2 1 
1 3 3 1 
1 4 6 4 1 
1 5 10 10 5 1 
1 6 15 20 15 6 1 
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1 
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
```

Answer (score 5):

### APL, <s>19</s> 15 characters

A bit late to the party, perhaps?

```
{⍪{⍵!⍨⍳⍵+1}¨⍳⍵}
```

It doesn't beat the J entry, though.

This assumes that the index origin (`⎕IO`) is set to `0`. Unfortunately, with an index origin of `1`, we need <s>25</s> 18 characters:

```
{⍪{⍵!⍨0,⍳⍵}¨1-⍨⍳⍵}
```

There are two `⍨`s in the code to express my frustration.

Demo:

```
      {⍪{⍵!⍨⍳⍵+1}¨⍳⍵}5
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

---

Explanations

Short version:

- `⍳⍵` (with an index origin of 0) produces an array of the numbers from 0 to `⍵-1` inclusive, where `⍵` is the right argument to the function.
- `⍳⍵+1` generates all numbers from 0 to `⍵`
- `{⍵!⍨⍳⍵+1}` generates `⍵` choose `k` for every element `k` in `⍳⍵+1`. The `⍨` (commute) operator swaps the arguments to a function around, such that the right hand argument becomes the left, and vice versa.
- `{⍵!⍨⍳⍵+1}¨⍳⍵` passes each element in `⍳⍵` using the `¨` (each) operator. The result is a one dimensional array containing the first `⍵` rows of the Pascal's Triangle.
- The one argument form of `⍪` takes a one dimensional vector, and makes it a column rather than a row. Each row of the triangle is put on its own line.

Long answer:

- Virtually the same as the other version, except that `1-⍨` is placed before an `⍳` to replicate an index origin of 0.
- `0,⍳⍵` with an index origin of 1 replicates `⍳⍵+1` with an index origin of 0.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, 37 bytes

```
s/\d+/$&+$'/eg,say$_="1 $_"for($a)x<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YPyZFW19FTVtFXT81Xac4sVIl3lbJUEElXiktv0hDJVGzwsbu/3/Lf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 77 Chars

```
$o[0]=1;for(1..<>){$"=" ";for(1..$_){$n[$_]=$o[$_]+$o[$_-1]}@o=@n;print"@o
"}
```

Example input

```
5
```

Example output

```
 1
 1 1
 1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
 1 4 6 4 1
```

Answer (score 4):

### C, <s>132</s> 127 characters

```
c[25][25],n,i,j;main(){for(scanf("%d",&n);i<n;i++)for(j=0;j<=i;j++)printf("%d%c",c[i][j]=j?c[i-1][j-1]+c[i-1][j]:1,i-j?32:10);}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 10 bytes

*Language created after this challenge*

```
1iq:"tTTY+
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MWlxOiJ0VFRZKw&input=OQ)

```
1       % Push a 1. This will be the first row
iq:     % Take input n. Generate range [1,2,...,n-1]
"       % For each (that is, repeat n-1 times)
  t     %   Duplicate latest row
  TT    %   Push [1 1]
  Y+    %   Convolve latest row with [1 1] to produce next row
        % Implicitly end for each
        % Implicitly display stack contents
```

Comment: non-competing but a holy disaster, none from previous submissions (even J) succeeded to reduce it up to how much **Matl** did !!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure Jelly or 05AB1E would be shorter though :-)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>70</s> 69 bytes

Generating Pascal's Triangle in a golfy manner has always given me brain ache but every time it comes up, I give it another try. Last night, armed with a few beers, I finally cracked it and came up with a *working* solution I was happy with. Fitting, then, that this should be my 500th (undeleted) solution here.

0-indexed and includes a trailing newline and a trailing space on each line.

```js
n=>(g=x=>x++>n?``:(h=z=>y>x?``:z+` `+h(z*(x-y)/y++))(y=1)+`
`+g(x))``
```

---

### Try it

```js
o.innerText=(f=
n=>(g=x=>x++>n?``:(h=z=>y>x?``:z+` `+h(z*(x-y)/y++))(y=1)+`
`+g(x))``)(i.value=8);oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o></pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

### D <s>134</s> 128 chars

```
import std.stdio;void main(){int n,m;int[]l,k=[0,1];readf("%d",&n);foreach(i;0..n){writeln(l=k~0);k=[];foreach(e;l)k~=m+(m=e);}}
```

output for 9 is

```
>9
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 4, 6, 4, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1, 0]
```

taking full advantage of "you may format it however you like"; there is a space between each number and a linebreak

edit repositioned the assignment to `l` to shave of some chars

Answer (score 3):

### Scala, 131 characters

```
object P extends App{var x=List(1)
while(x.size<=args(0).toInt){println(x.mkString(" "))
x=(0+:x:+0).sliding(2).map(_.sum).toList}}
```

Takes the input from the command line.

Output for n=10:

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
1 5 10 10 5 1
1 6 15 20 15 6 1
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
```

Comment: What's with all those `0`s :-)?

Comment: @mellamokb Bit of re-arranging made them go away and shortened the code. :-)

Answer (score 3):

### F♯ - 203 characters

My first attempt at a round of code golf, and first attempt at functional programming. There is probably some obvious way to shorten it I haven't quite figured out yet. It complies in VS2010s F♯ compiler (which has the effect of running #light by default unlike earlier versions), and also works in the F♯ interpreter. Accepts input via stdin. Wish there was a better way for the input/output though! Lots of characters!

```
open System
let rec C r m =if r=0||m<=0||m>=r then 1 else C(r-1)m+C(r-1)(m-1)
for j = 0 to Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine ()) do (
 [0..j]|>List.map(C j)|>List.iter(fun k->printf "%i " k)
 printf "\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

*Why is there no accepted answer to this question?*

### VBA - 249 chars

```vb
Sub t(n)
ReDim a(1 To n,1 To n*2)
a(1,n)=1:y=vbCr:z=" ":d=z & 1 & z & y:For b=2 To n:For c=1 To n*2:x=a(b-1,c)
If c>1 Then a(b,c)=a(b-1,c-1)+x
If c<n*2 Then a(b,c)=a(b-1,c+1)+x
d=IIf(a(b,c)<>0,d & z & a(b,c) & z,d):Next:d=d & y:Next:MsgBox d
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

postscript - 59 chars (63 if you count `-dn=` to get the number of rows in)

```
[1]n{dup ==[0 3 2 roll{dup 3 2 roll add exch}forall]}repeat
```

run with

```
gs -q -dn=10 -dBATCH pascal.ps
```

to get

```
[1]
[1 1]
[1 2 1]
[1 3 3 1]
[1 4 6 4 1]
[1 5 10 10 5 1]
[1 6 15 20 15 6 1]
[1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1]
[1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1]
[1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 35 chars

Here is the dull and lazy way of slicing Pascal's triangle:

```
Table[n~Binomial~k,{n,0,5},{k,0,n}]

(* out *)
{{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 3, 1}, {1, 4, 6, 4, 1}, {1, 5, 10, 10,5, 1}}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Maple, 46

```
seq(print(seq(binomial(i,k),k=0..i)),i=0..n-1)
```

Usage:

```
> f:=n->seq(print(seq(binomial(i,k),k=0..i)),i=0..n-1);
> f(3)
    1
   1 1
  1 2 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## VBA, <s>162</s> <s>142</s> <s>102</s> 80 bytes

<sub><sup>Saved 22 bytes thanks to Taylor Scott.</sup></sub>

<sub>This is an old question now but I saw a shorter solution for VBA.</sub>

```vba
[B2].Resize([A1],[A1])="=IF(COLUMN()>ROW(),"""",IF(ROW()=2,1,IFERROR(A1+B1,1)))"
```

This is meant to be run in the immediate window. Input is in cell `A1` of the active worksheet. Output is in the active worksheet starting at `B2` and using however many cells are required based on the input. The `COLUMN()>ROW()` check keeps the top right of the triangle blank. The `ROW()=2` check makes the first value `1` to initiate the triangle. I could have shifted the output down and dropped this check, but it introduces a lot of extraneous output before the actual triangle and I didn't feel that it was in the spirit of the challenge.

I originally posted a much more complicated method that calculated every value based on its row and column. All this method does, though, is to use in-cell formulas. I start at `B2` so I can reference the row above it without `#REF!` errors. Then, it copies and pastes the same formula over a block of cells *n* wide and *n* tall. The input and output for `n=25` looks like this:

[image: Output]

Comment: Very cool answer, but you can golf this quite a bit. Converting `Function p(r)` to `Sub p(r)` since you have no function output value, removing the space from `debug.? c(n,k);` and converting the multiline `if-then-else` statement to a single line (`If k Then c=c(n-1,k-1)*n/k Else c=1`) brings the byte-count down to `130` by my count

Comment: @TaylorScott Thanks! I'm pretty new at golfing and only slightly less new to programming in general. I counted 142 because of the line breaks. From [what I could find](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6893/38183), those are supposed to count.

Comment: Ah, you are right, I did forget to count my newlines, and as it turns out, at least one other golfing trick `For n=0 To...` can be condensed to `For n=0To...` bringing my version of the code to `Sub p(r):For n=0To r-1:For k=0To n:Debug.?c(n,k);:Next:Debug.?:Next:End Sub`
 `Function c(n,k):If k Then c=1 Else c=c(n-1,k-1)*n/k` [char(10)] 
`End Function` with a byte count of `139`

Comment: A second look at this suggests that if you break it down into an immediate window function with a helper function, you can get it down to 112 Bytes (Immediate Window Function: `For n=0To[A1-1]:For k=0To n:?c(n,k);:Next:?:Next` Helper Function: `Function c(n,k)`
`If k Then c=c(n-1,k-1)*n/k Else c=1`
`End Function`)

Comment: @TaylorScott I found an even shorter way using the immediate window. I had not previously considered the basic formula approach but it turned out to be way shorter.

Comment: since you moved over to a cell based response you can optimize this by removing the copy and instead always deleting `[A:A]` and `[1:1]` instead yielding `[B2].Resize([A1],[A1])="=IF(COLUMN()>ROW(),"""",IFERROR(A1+B1,1))":[1:1].Delete:[A:A].Delete` for 92 Bytes  - I tried golfing down the delete statements and I am convinced that there is a way to do it, but for now I cannot seem to condense them

Comment: @TaylorScott What about just dropping them entirely? With a change in the formula, it works just fine. I think that output starting at `B2` instead of `A1` is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 66+1 bytes

```php
for($a[]=1;$k||$argn>=$k=++$i;)echo$a[--$k]+=$a[$k-1],$k?" ":"
";
```

**65+1 bytes in PHP 5.5 or later:**

```php
for($a=[1];$k||$argn>=$k=++$i;)echo$a[--$k]+=$a[$k-1]," 
"[!$k];
```

Note that the first line has a trailing space!

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f0215cdb9b5ec43ebeaa2e1662e19b0686cc9375).

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
{x#x{+':x,0}\1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqrpCuaJaW92qQsegNsaw9n@agul/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-s`, <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
LaPl+:lPE!l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fJzEgR9sqJ8BVMef///@6xf8tAQ)

#### Explanation

Each row of the triangle, represented as a list, can be obtained by adding two copies of the previous row with an offset:

```
 [1 2 1]
+  [1 2 1]
----------
 [1 3 3 1]
```

Pip's default behavior when adding two lists is almost perfect: it matches up the elements and adds them pairwise, and if one list is longer, the extra numbers in that list are retained unchanged. So all we have to do is offset one list by prepending a 0:

```
 [1 2 1]
+[0 1 2 1]
----------
 [1 3 3 1]
```

Here's the version I started with before golfing:

```
Y[1]La{Pyy+:yPE0}
                   a is command-line argument (implicit)
Y[1]               Yank list representing the first row into y
    La{         }  Loop a times:
       Py           Print the current row (space-separated, thanks to -s flag)
            yPE0    Construct a list which is y with 0 prepended
         y+:        Add that to y and assign the result back to y
```

My original golfed version applied a few tricks:

- Using [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211993/16766), `[1]` → `^1`.
- We can save the curly braces if the loop body is one statement, which we can accomplish by printing `y` in the expression that updates `y`: `y+:(Py)PE0`.
- We can then save the parentheses by changing `yPE0` (`y` with `0` prepended) to `0ALy` (`0` with the list `y` appended; `0` gets promoted to a singleton list `[0]` first). This leaves us with `y+:0AL(Py)`, but since `P` is unary we can drop the parentheses (though we still need a space between the operators): `y+:0AL Py`.

The resulting solution is 14 bytes:

```
Y^1Lay+:0AL Py
```

*But we can do better!*

- It would be nice to save the space before `P`; also, the initialization `Y^1` is rather expensive.
- If we could start from an empty list (as the "0th" row) and print each row *after* it is updated, we could solve both problems: we could use `l` (which is preinitialized to the empty list) instead of `y`, and the `P` would come immediately after the loop header and therefore not require a separator.
- The problem is that our update logic, "prepend a 0 and add," doesn't work for the first row: it gives `[] + [0] = [0]`, when we need `[1]`.
- *But*, if we can prepend a 1 on the first iteration and a 0 every other time, we'll be golden. On the first iteration, `l` is empty (falsey); on every other iteration, `l` is nonempty (truthy). So we can simply prepend `!l`.

This approach gives us our 11-byte solution:

```
LaPl+:lPE!l
La           Loop a times:
         !l   1 if l is empty, 0 otherwise
      lPE     Construct a list which is l with that value prepended
   l+:        Add that to l and assign the result back to l
  P           Print (space-separated: -s flag)
```

Comment: I knew mine wasn't the shortest, but not by this much.  What a clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
FN©>F®Ne})ˆ}¯»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@/md2ilnduhdX6ptZqn22oPrT@0@/9/MwA)

---

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
1 5 10 10 5 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
3Bj+2\
1Ç⁸’¤Ð¡K€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ASEA3v//M0JqKzJcCjHDh@KBuOKAmcKkw5DCoUvigqxZ////MjU)

If "provided however is most convenient in your chosen language" means that I can use 0-indexed input instead of 1-indexed, then `’¤` can be removed for -2.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 38 bytes

```r
for(i in 0:scan())print(choose(i,0:i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwcCqODkxT0NTs6AoM69EIzkjP784VSNTx8AqU1Pzv6HBfwA)

The [other R answer is good](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3825/67312), but this is shorter, and that one still needs a call to `scan()`!

In R, `choose` is vectorized over `k` so this is a neat solution. `print` also prints out the element number at the start of each line, so if that's not valid, I can change this to a 41 byte solution,

```r
for(i in 0:scan())cat(choose(i,0:i),'\n')
```

Comment: I think you output one line too many every time (though neat solution indeed).

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
<ÝεDÝc}»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f5vDcc1tdDs9Nrj20@/9/SwA)

Comment: I... you... I.... what?!

Comment: `1¸=©sF®NF®«ü+®ì}®«=`... I'm ashamed tbh lol. `nCr`, never seen it used until this answer.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: I have used it before, but I can't remember in what/which answer(s). Sometimes I wish I had a searchable version of all answers that I could check when I feel like I've done something similar (and maybe better) in the past.

Comment: Maybe a search for all answers by `user:##` then extract all indented code blocks that follow a line starting with `#[05AB1E]` using the SE API :P?

Comment: I wanted to do that to find all questions with more than 1 05AB1E answer on it.

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fzc/l8NxkzUO7//@3BAA) by using a ranged loop without `}`.

Answer (score 2):

## Malbolge Unshackled (20-trit rotation variant), 3,2485e7 bytes

Size of this answer exceeds maximum postable program size (eh), so the code is [located in my GitHub repository](https://github.com/KrzysztofSzewczyk/codegolf-submissions/raw/master/3815.7z).

It's a slow monstrosity, but I love this one. The digits are being displayed in hexadecimal form.

Btw, the code is compressed using 7Zip and PPMd algorithm, because the program is plain too big to post to Github in it's state of art.

### How to run this?

This might be a tricky part, because naive Haskell interpreter will take ages upon ages to run this. TIO has decent Malbogle Unshackled interpreter, but sadly I won't be able to use it (limitations).

The best one I could find is the fixed 20-trit rotation width variant, that performs very well.

To make the interpreter a bit faster, I've removed all the checks from Matthias Lutter's Malbolge Unshackled interpreter.

My modified version can run around 6,3% faster.

```c
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* translation = "5z]&gqtyfr$(we4{WP)H-Zn,[%\\3dL+Q;>U!pJS72Fh"
        "OA1CB6v^=I_0/8|jsb9m<.TVac`uY*MK'X~xDl}REokN:#?G\"i@";

typedef struct Word {
    unsigned int area;
    unsigned int high;
    unsigned int low;
} Word;

void word2string(Word w, char* s, int min_length) {
    if (!s) return;
    if (min_length < 1) min_length = 1;
    if (min_length > 20) min_length = 20;
    s[0] = (w.area%3) + '0';
    s[1] = 't';
    char tmp[20];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        tmp[19-i] = (w.low % 3) + '0';
        w.low /= 3;
    }
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        tmp[9-i] = (w.high % 3) + '0';
        w.high /= 3;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (tmp[i] == s[0] && i < 20 - min_length) i++;
    int j = 2;
    while (i < 20) {
        s[j] = tmp[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    s[j] = 0;
}

unsigned int crazy_low(unsigned int a, unsigned int d){
    unsigned int crz[] = {1,0,0,1,0,2,2,2,1};
    int position = 0;
    unsigned int output = 0;
    while (position < 10){
        unsigned int i = a%3;
        unsigned int j = d%3;
        unsigned int out = crz[i+3*j];
        unsigned int multiple = 1;
        int k;
        for (k=0;k<position;k++)
            multiple *= 3;
        output += multiple*out;
        a /= 3;
        d /= 3;
        position++;
    }
    return output;
}

Word zero() {
    Word result = {0, 0, 0};
    return result;
}

Word increment(Word d) {
    d.low++;
    if (d.low >= 59049) {
        d.low = 0;
        d.high++;
        if (d.high >= 59049) {
            fprintf(stderr,"error: overflow\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return d;
}

Word decrement(Word d) {
    if (d.low == 0) {
        d.low = 59048;
        d.high--;
    }else{
        d.low--;
    }
    return d;
}

Word crazy(Word a, Word d){
    Word output;
    unsigned int crz[] = {1,0,0,1,0,2,2,2,1};
    output.area = crz[a.area+3*d.area];
    output.high = crazy_low(a.high, d.high);
    output.low = crazy_low(a.low, d.low);
    return output;
}

Word rotate_r(Word d){
    unsigned int carry_h = d.high%3;
    unsigned int carry_l = d.low%3;
    d.high = 19683 * carry_l + d.high / 3;
    d.low = 19683 * carry_h + d.low / 3;
    return d;
}

// last_initialized: if set, use to fill newly generated memory with preinitial values...
Word* ptr_to(Word** mem[], Word d, unsigned int last_initialized) {
    if ((mem[d.area])[d.high]) {
        return &(((mem[d.area])[d.high])[d.low]);
    }
    (mem[d.area])[d.high] = (Word*)malloc(59049 * sizeof(Word));
    if (!(mem[d.area])[d.high]) {
        fprintf(stderr,"error: out of memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (last_initialized) {
        Word repitition[6];
        repitition[(last_initialized-1) % 6] =
                ((mem[0])[(last_initialized-1) / 59049])
                    [(last_initialized-1) % 59049];
        repitition[(last_initialized) % 6] =
                ((mem[0])[last_initialized / 59049])
                    [last_initialized % 59049];
        unsigned int i;
        for (i=0;i<6;i++) {
            repitition[(last_initialized+1+i) % 6] =
                    crazy(repitition[(last_initialized+i) % 6],
                        repitition[(last_initialized-1+i) % 6]);
        }
        unsigned int offset = (59049*d.high) % 6;
        i = 0;
        while (1){
            ((mem[d.area])[d.high])[i] = repitition[(i+offset)%6];
            if (i == 59048) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return &(((mem[d.area])[d.high])[d.low]);
}

unsigned int get_instruction(Word** mem[], Word c,
        unsigned int last_initialized,
        int ignore_invalid) {
    Word* instr = ptr_to(mem, c, last_initialized);
    unsigned int instruction = instr->low;
    instruction = (instruction+c.low + 59049 * c.high
            + (c.area==1?52:(c.area==2?10:0)))%94;
    return instruction;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Word** memory[3];
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        memory[i] = (Word**)malloc(59049 * sizeof(Word*));
        if (!memory) {
            fprintf(stderr,"not enough memory.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        for (j=0; j<59049; j++) {
            (memory[i])[j] = 0;
        }
    }
    Word a, c, d;
    unsigned int result;
    FILE* file;
    if (argc < 2) {
        // read program code from STDIN
        file = stdin;
    }else{
        file = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    }
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File not found: %s\n",argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    a = zero();
    c = zero();
    d = zero();
    result = 0;
    while (!feof(file)){
        unsigned int instr;
        Word* cell = ptr_to(memory, d, 0);
        (*cell) = zero();
        result = fread(&cell->low,1,1,file);
        if (result > 1)
            return 1;
        if (result == 0 || cell->low == 0x1a || cell->low == 0x04)
            break;
        instr = (cell->low + d.low + 59049*d.high)%94;
        if (cell->low == ' ' || cell->low == '\t' || cell->low == '\r'
                || cell->low == '\n');
        else if (cell->low >= 33 && cell->low < 127 &&
                (instr == 4 || instr == 5 || instr == 23 || instr == 39
                    || instr == 40 || instr == 62 || instr == 68
                    || instr == 81)) {
            d = increment(d);
        }
    }
    if (file != stdin) {
        fclose(file);
    }
    unsigned int last_initialized = 0;
    while (1){
        *ptr_to(memory, d, 0) = crazy(*ptr_to(memory, decrement(d), 0),
                *ptr_to(memory, decrement(decrement(d)), 0));
        last_initialized = d.low + 59049*d.high;
        if (d.low == 59048) {
            break;
        }
        d = increment(d);
    }
    d = zero();

    unsigned int step = 0;
    while (1) {
        unsigned int instruction = get_instruction(memory, c,
                last_initialized, 0);
        step++;
        switch (instruction){
            case 4:
                c = *ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized);
                break;
            case 5:
                if (!a.area) {
                    printf("%c",(char)(a.low + 59049*a.high));
                }else if (a.area == 2 && a.low == 59047
                        && a.high == 59048) {
                    printf("\n");
                }
                break;
            case 23:
                a = zero();
                a.low = getchar();
                if (a.low == EOF) {
                    a.low = 59048;
                    a.high = 59048;
                    a.area = 2;
                }else if (a.low == '\n'){
                    a.low = 59047;
                    a.high = 59048;
                    a.area = 2;
                }
                break;
            case 39:
                a = (*ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized)
                        = rotate_r(*ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized)));
                break;
            case 40:
                d = *ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized);
                break;
            case 62:
                a = (*ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized)
                        = crazy(a, *ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized)));
                break;
            case 81:
                return 0;
            case 68:
            default:
                break;
        }

        Word* mem_c = ptr_to(memory, c, last_initialized);
        mem_c->low = translation[mem_c->low - 33];

        c = increment(c);
        d = increment(d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### It's working (very slowly!)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>16</s> 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
_ä+T p1}h[1â]
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=X%2bQrVCBwMX1oWzHiXQ&footer=y3EiICJ9IPs&input=MTAKMg)

```
_äÈ+Y}0 p1}      // f = prepend 0 to array and sums each pairs, then appends 1
           h[1â] // run f input times starting with [[1]]
```

saved 3 thanks to @Shaggy

Comment: `ä+T` will work here, too.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-s`, <s><sup>22</sup></s> 21 bytes

```
La{PooMP:_+BoPU1oPB1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fJ7E6ID/fN8AqXtspPyDUMD/AybD2////usX/TQE)

This was simpler than trying to map an iterable, and probably shorter.

-1 byte from Dlosc, using the `PU` and `PB` functions.

### Explanation (old)

```
La{Poo:1AL(_+BMPo)AL1} a → input, o → 1(predefined)
La{                  } loop a times
   Po                  print variable o(joined by spaces due to -s)
     o:                assign o to:
          (_+BMPo)     sums of pairs of it's elements
       1AL        AL1  with 1 added on both sides
```

Comment: I just remembered that `PU` and `PB` return lvalues, so: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fJ7E6ID8/INQgwMnAN8AqXtup9v///7rF/00B).

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), <s><sup>58</sup></s> 53 bytes

```forth
: P 0 ?do 1 i for dup . i * j i - 1+ / next cr loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYjLDYAgFMBW6VmDwlUPrsAOIn5ifIRg4vZPuLRNo@RymD02qU54LEsQHCd1Et7EULvjqjS4npFn@wpr5hZJzOosXn8)

This is a heavily shortened version of the implementation [here,](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#C) which was in turn, translated from C.

-5 bytes from Bubbler.

The function is called like: `<input> P`.

Comment: When you need to loop from 0 to n inclusive, [for loop can be shorter](https://tio.run/##FYjLDYAgFMBW6VmDwlUPrsAOIn5ifIRg4vZPuLRNo@RymD02qU54LEsQHCd1Et7EULvjqjS4npFn@wpr5hZJzOosXn8).

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 58 bytes

```scala
Seq.iterate(Seq(1),_){r=>1+:(r,r.tail).zipped.map(_+_):+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Ou5fEQcrSwmpEhHlqQbJtQ)

Somewhat based upon [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211987/95792) other Scala answer.

```scala
Seq.iterate(                 //Make a Seq
  Seq(1),                      //starting with just [1]
  _                            //of length n (_ is shorthand for n=>...n...
){ r =>                      //Function to get next row from previous row r
  (r,r.tail).zipped.map(_+_)    //Add each cell with the one on its right
1+:                         :+1 //Put two 1's around it
}
```

## Scala 3, 54 bytes

```scala
Seq.iterate(Seq(1),_){r=>1+:r.zip(r.tail).map(_+_):+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Ii6GFeLiTGy9FAnBsgYnqA)

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 58

Input in arbitrary cell. Assign it named range "N". (+1 count)

Then use

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(COMBIN(SEQUENCE(N,1,),SEQUENCE(1,N,
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Mj`, 4 bytes

```
ƛʀƈṄ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=Mj&code=%C6%9B%CA%80%C6%88%E1%B9%84&inputs=6&header=&footer=)

-2 bytes thanks to Lyxal

Comment: The `:` is unnecessary.

Comment: [4 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=Mj&code=%C6%9B%CA%80%C6%88%E1%B9%84&inputs=6&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 31 bytes

```
{1,{.put;|$_,0 Z+0,|$_}...$_+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJaoYPu/2lCnWq@gtMS6RiVex0AhSttAB8iq1dPTU4nXNqz9n6hhqfkfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>105</s> 92 characters

```php
for($e=1;$e++<=$i;$n=$a,$a=''){ 
foreach($n as $k=>$v)$a[]=$v+$n[$k-1];
$a[]=1;print_r($a);}
```

Input: `$i = 9;`

Output:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 15
    [3] => 20
    [4] => 15
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 21
    [3] => 35
    [4] => 35
    [5] => 21
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 28
    [3] => 56
    [4] => 70
    [5] => 56
    [6] => 28
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 1
)
```

Comment: nice one, though predefined variables are no valid input method.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 105 chars

```
A=[1]
for i in range(input()):
    B=[sum(A[j:j+2])for j in range(i)]
    B[:0]=[1]
    B[i+1:]=[1]
    print A
    A=B
```

Comment: You can spare 4 characters with list slice: replace `B.insert(0,1)` with `B[:0]=[1]`.

Comment: Yeah! I'm not a very advanced python programmer. And I've changed both of them.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 108 (126)

Length depends on whether the #include can be omitted, as it is some other C examples. Code uses edk.h as the shortest (Microsoft) standard C header with stdio.h included.

```c
#include <edk.h>
int a[25]={1},b,c,d;main(){for(scanf("%d",&d);c++<d;)for(b=c;b--;printf("%d%c",a[b],b?32:10),a[b+1]+=a[b]);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>124</s> <s>118</s> 114 bytes

```
r([A,B|R],[C|S]):-C is A+B,r([B|R],S).
r(L,L).
t(L,I):-I=0;write(L),nl,r([0|L],M),J is I-1,t(M,J).
t(N):-t([1],N).
```

The predicate `t(N)` outputs `N` rows of Pascal's triangle. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/v0gj2lHHqSYoVifauSY4VtNK11khs1jBUdtJBygFlgjW1OMq0vDR8QHSJUDaE6jI09bAurwosyRVw0dTJy8HpNagxidWx1dTxwuk31PXUKdEw1fHC6zHD6ijRCPaMFbHT1PvP4htCaQB)

Note that if you're running this locally, Prolog will probably tell you there's more than one result; if you ask for the next result, it might either output some invalid row(s) or print ever-increasing rows of the triangle till it crashes. I don't think this invalidates the solution, since it behaves exactly as desired on TIO. At any rate, a 4-byte fix is to add a couple of "cuts": insert `,!` before the period at the end of line 1, and again after `I=0` in line 3.

#### Ungolfed, with comments

```
% nextRow/2 takes the current row (with a zero prepended) and builds the next row
% Example: nextRow([0, 1, 2, 1], X) gives X = [1, 3, 3, 1]

% Base case: we've gotten down to the final 1, which stays the same in the next row
nextRow([1], [1]).
% Recursive case: an element in the next row is the sum of the two elements
% above it in the current row
nextRow([A, B | Tail], [C | NewTail]) :- C is A+B, nextRow([B | Tail], NewTail).

% triangle/2 takes the current row and the number of rows left and outputs that
% many rows

% Base case: no rows left; we're done
triangle(_, 0) :- !.
% Recursive case: output the current row, build the next row, and recurse with
% decremented number of rows left
triangle(Row, RowsLeft) :-
  write(Row), nl,
  nextRow([0 | Row], NewRow),
  NewRowsLeft is RowsLeft-1,
  triangle(NewRow, NewRowsLeft).

% triangle/1 takes the number of rows N and outputs that many rows starting from [1]

triangle(N) :- triangle([1], N).
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, <s>143</s> 138 bytes

```java
r->{var s="";for(int i=0,j;i++<r;s+="\n")for(j=0;j++<i;s+=p(i,j)+" ");return s;}int p(int r,int k){return--r<1|k<2|k>r?1:p(r,k-1)+p(r,k);}
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hZC7coMwEEV7f8UOlTQ8bNIlAucLQpMySSFj4YiHYFYLGQ/m24kE6TOj195daXVuLScZ19dmLVtpLbxJbeYDgDaksJKlgsKHAO@E2tygZC4DyIUTFzfdKMBADivG53mSCDYPAlH1uBXq/BTVQodhhsKGefBpAu5zdX4StVO1Vwemo5qHAQRcoKIRDVixHIRvezxC0RMMEgn6CuhbweVOKi770dDBtxj2H0V@bfi8PxDHmKWPJnt6NGd8TV8GhlETpzzcDlwsK8AwXlpdgiVJbpt6fYXO0bOd9OMLJN/RvSfQOUajfraAbfjOk7sl1SX9SMng7lBrWJeYpGQp/6/imf9ZuKy/)

```java
r->{                     // Method with integer parameter and String return-type
  var s="";              //  Result-String, starting empty
  for(int i=0,j;i++<r;   //  Loop `i` in the range [1, `r`]:
      s+="\n")           //    After every iteration: Append a new-line
    for(j=0;j++<i;       //   Inner loop `j` in the range [1, `i`]:
      s+=p(i,j)          //    Append the `j`'th Pascal Triangle number on the `i`'th row
         +" ");          //    and also append a space
  return s;}             //  Return the result-String

// Separated recursive method to get the k'th value of the r'th row in the Pascal Triangle
int p(int r,int k){return--r<1|k<2|k>r?1:p(r,k-1)+p(r,k);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

If the output format was less restrictive, then this could be 8 bytes (just remove '`Á`')

```
řĐř⁻⇹⁻⇹ćÁ
```

Explanation:

```
               Implicit input (n)   
ř              Push [1,2,...,n]
 Đ             Duplicate top of stack
  ř            Push [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],...,[1,2,...,n]]
   ⁻           Decrement element-wise [[0],[0,1],[0,1,2],...,[0,1,...,n-1]]
    ⇹          Swap top two elements on stack
     ⁻         Decrement [0,1,2,...,n-1]
      ⇹        Swap top of stack
       ć       Compute nCr†
        Á      Push contents of array on top of stack to the stack
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6MwjE47OfNS4@1H7Tgh5pP1w4///pgA)

† - This yields [[0C0],[1C0,1C1],[2C0,2C1,2C2],...,[(n-1)C0,(n-1)C1,...,(n-1)C(n-1)]]

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 68 Bytes

```
b=lambda n,a=[1]:n and[print(a),b(n-1,[*map(sum,zip([0]+a,a+[0]))])]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 97 bytes

```scala
n=>{var p=Seq(1);for(i<-0 to n-1){println(p mkString " ");p=1+:0.to(i-1).map(j=>p(j)+p(j+1)):+1}}
```

A for loop computes the next line's number sequence from the previous one via simple index-based addition and by concatenating 1's via `+:` and `:+`. Unfortunately this iterative approach is slightly shorter than a "nicer" monadic approach via scanLeft :)

**Edit**: Thanks to all commentors for tips & corrections!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYpBC4MgGEDv/YqPTooUeq0Z7LjboO0HuGZhs0@nEoPotzsv7/HgxUlZld1r1VOCu4ol4yMYhYvVoH9J4zvC1Xs4qmpXFuYObphADvBEU5xRDseuAng56i8RtJ9dIObScEgOsBH08MFgskg8bJ8xlVighpr2XgrW8TY5YsrWbsqTVQ4FlBUwQWnHxHnmmQhOqzP/AQ)

Comment: I don't think you can accept input through variables that aren't passed to a function. Luckily, it only costs [2 bytes](https://tio.run/##DYpBC4MgGEDv/YqPTooUeq0Z7LjboO0HuGZhs0@nEoPotzsv7/HgxUlZld1r1VOCu4ol4yMYhYvVoH9J4zvC1Xs4qmpXFuYObphADvBEU5xRDseuAng56i8RtJ9dIObScEgOsBH08MFgskg8bJ8xlVighpr2XgrW8TY5YsrWbsqTVQ4FlBUwQWnHxHnmmQhOqzP/AQ) more if you golf it some more.

Comment: You can actually get [71 bytes](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/n1tild3wRnW5rKhamHC2eg) using `scanLeft`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), 37 bytes

```
f(x)=@show 1(x<2||[0;F=f(x-1)]+[F;0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0//8/TaNC09ahOCO/XMFQo8LGqKYm2sDazRYorGuoGasd7WZtEKsJVGVkqvkfAA)

It outputs a lot of garbage but it's allowed:

```
1 * (x < 2 || [0; F = f(x - 1)] + [F; 0]) = 1
1 * (x < 2 || [0; F = f(x - 1)] + [F; 0]) = [1, 1]
1 * (x < 2 || [0; F = f(x - 1)] + [F; 0]) = [1, 2, 1]
1 * (x < 2 || [0; F = f(x - 1)] + [F; 0]) = [1, 3, 3, 1]
1 * (x < 2 || [0; F = f(x - 1)] + [F; 0]) = [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ḶcŻ$€K€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm3JR3erPGpa4w3Ekf///7cEAA)

Mmm yes the output format here really do be fun tho - 5 bytes for the triangle generation, and 3 for the formatting.

### Explained

```
ḶcŻ$€K€Y # A monadic chain with argument n. Let the current value be λ
Ḷ        # λ = [0, n)
    €    # over each item in λ:
 cŻ$     #   yield item choose [0, item] (vectorising)
     K€  # join each sublist on spaces
       Y # and join that on newlines
```

Comment: The output format is somewhat lenient here, so `G` works in place of `K€Y`.

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8zkhzu2abr////fEgA)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 48 bytes

Takes input \$n\$ from cell `A1` and outputs an \$n\times n\$ lower triangular matrix as a spilled array to the calling cell.

```vb
=IfError(Combin(Sequence(A1),Sequence(1,A1)),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$19\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 15.639 bytes

```
#jej/ #GWW1O'+Jx0J0
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyIjamVqLyAjR1dXMU8nK0p4MEowIiwiOSJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
LıDĖ€cðj
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kp9S7IKlpSVpuhZrfY5sdDky7VHTmuTDG7KWFCclF0NlFiy0hDAA)

But, if outputting a nested list was ok:

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 bytes

```
LıDĖ€c
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWq3yObHQ5Mu1R05rkJcVJycVQ4QULLSEMAA)

##### Explanation

```python
LıDĖ€cðj  # Implicit input
Lı        # Map over the range [0..input)
  D       #  Duplicate the current number
   Ė€     #  Map over the range [0..number]
     c    #   Compute the binomial coefficient
      ðj  #  Join the row by spaces
          # Implicit output, joined by newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 111 characters

I know this can be improved on, just a first try:

```perl
$r=<>;
@p=(1);
while($r--){
    print join(' ',@p)."\n";
    @q=@p;
    unshift @q,0;
    push @p,0;
    $i=0;
    foreach(@p){$_+=$q[$i++];}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom 64 bytes

```
p(n)==for j in 0..n-1 repeat output[binomial(j,i) for i in 0..j]
```

results

```
(74) -> p 1
   Compiling function p with type PositiveInteger -> Void
   [1]
                                                               Type: Void
(75) -> p 2
   [1]
   [1,1]
                                                               Type: Void
(76) -> p 9
   [1]
   [1,1]
   [1,2,1]
   [1,3,3,1]
   [1,4,6,4,1]
   [1,5,10,10,5,1]
   [1,6,15,20,15,6,1]
   [1,7,21,35,35,21,7,1]
   [1,8,28,56,70,56,28,8,1]
                                                               Type: Void
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 178 bytes

```c
#define x p[i][j]
p[25][51]={0};i;j;f(n){p[0][25]=1;for(i=1;i<n;i++)for(j=1;j<50;j++)x=p[i-1][j-1]+p[i-1][j+1];for(i=0;i<n;i++,putchar(10))for(j=0;j<51;j++)if(x)printf("%d ",x);}
```

**Uniformly Padded, 244 bytes**

```c
#define x p[i][j]
s[25]={1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7};p[25][51]={0};i;j;f(n){p[0][25]=1;for(i=1;i<n;i++)for(j=1;j<50;j++)x=p[i-1][j-1]+p[i-1][j+1];for(i=0;i<n;i++,putchar(10))for(j=0;j<51;j++)if(x)printf("%*d ",s[n-1],x);}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/JjZ0H9)

**Detailed**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 15;
    int s[25]={1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3, 4,4,4, 5,5,5,5, 6,6,6, 7,7};
    int p[25][25+1+25] = { 0 };
    p[0][25] = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < (25+1+24); j++)
        {
            p[i][j] = p[i-1][j-1] + p[i-1][j+1];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < (25+1+25); j++)
        {
            if(p[i][j])
            {
                printf("%*d ",s[n-1],p[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 17 bytes

```
¶↑:;1´o¡ȯmΣ∂Ṫ*´e1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9odXNr///CtuKGkTo7McK0b8KhyK9tzqPiiILhuaoqwrRlMf//)

#### Explanation

Idea is to use polynomial multiplication beginning with `[1,1]` and iterate multiplication, take N elements from the resulting infinite list:

```
¶↑:;1´(¡(mΣ∂Ṫ*))´e1  -- implicit input N
                ´e1  -- duplicate 1 & listify: [1,1]
     ´(        )     -- duplicate [1,1] and apply to:
       ¡(mΣ∂Ṫ*)      --   iterate the function (see below*)
                     -- [[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],…
   ;1                -- listify 1: [1]
  :                  -- prepend: [[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],…
 ↑                   -- take N elements
¶                    -- join with newlines
```

<sup>* That function handles the multiplication, as described [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150681/48198).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
m.cLdh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1cv2ScFSFsAAA)

---

```
Code    |Explanation
--------+------------------------------
m.cLdh  |Full code
m.cLdhdQ|With implicit variables filled
--------+------------------------------
m      Q|For each d in [0, input):
   L hd | For each k in [0, d]:
 .c d   |  dCk
   L    | Collect results in a list
m       |Collect results in a list
        |Print result (implicit)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) -r, 50 bytes

```
limit(.;[1]|recurse([.[-1,keys[]:][:2]|add]))|@tsv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8nMzezREPPOtowtqYoNbm0qDhVI1ovWtdQJzu1sjg61io22sootiYxJSVWU7PGoaS47P9/Q4N/@QUlmfl5xf91iwA)

Answer (score -1):

## C, 311 bytes

```
r(int*s,int*o,int n){int h=1;while(h<=n){if(h==2){printf("%d %d\n",1,1);o[0]=1;o[1]=1;}else if(h==1){printf("%d\n",1);o[0]=1;}else{int j=0;int*s_p=s,*o_p=o;*o_p++=1;printf("1 ");while(j<(h-2)){*o_p+=*s_p++;*o_p+++=*s_p;printf("%d ",*(o_p-1));j++;}*o_p=1;printf("1\n");}memcpy(s,o,100);memset(o,0,100);h++;}}
```

The complete, readable version of the program is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void row(int *s,int *o,int n)
{   int h = 1;

    while (h <= n)
    {
    
    if(h==2){printf("%d %d\n",1,1);o[0]=1;o[1]=1;}
    
    else if(h==1){printf("%d\n",1);o[0]=1;}

    else
    {
        int j = 0; int *s_p=s,*o_p=o;*o_p++ =1;printf("1 ");

        while(j<(h-2))
        {
            *o_p += *s_p++;
            
            *o_p++ += *s_p;
            
            printf("%d ",*(o_p-1));
            
            j++;
        }
        
        *o_p=1;printf("1 ");puts("");
    }
        memset(s,0,100);memcpy(s,o,100);memset(o,0,100);h++;

    }
    
}

int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
    const int n = strtol(argv[1],0,10);
    
    row(n);
}
```

Comment: You can use a shorter function name to save some bytes.

Comment: I renamed the function to r. Thanks.

Comment: Extra whitespace, long variable names, unecessary parentheses, lists can be declared outside the function to remove the `static int`, first `memset` is not needed, `100`s can be `99`, the `puts` can be combined with the `printf`, second `o[0]=1;` can be removed

Comment: Got rid of the first memset and unnecessary puts. I don't know what you mean by replacing 100 with 99 because if n == 25 and since sizeof(int)==4, then I think it should remain a 100.

Comment: You don't need to reset the last element since you don't need to support the 26th iteration. Why did you put the lists back in the input? The question only specifies `n` as input, and you aren't using them as output? You still have the long variable names and the extra `o[0]=1`

Comment: Your complete version of the code does not work