# shortest possible python pascal triangle code

Tags: python

the contest is already finished, so I don't think it's cheating to ask:
I am trying to optimize this small contest: [pascal triangle](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/pascal)
I started with 4.72 and worked myself up to 7.48.
The best made a 9.05 but in perl, python2 best score is 8.25.
Unfortunately they don't let you look at what others did.
My current solution is the following:

```
l=[1]
print 1
while(len(l)<31):
 print' '.join(map(str,l+[1]))
 l=[1]+map(lambda x,y:x+y,l,l[1:]+[1])
```

Now I tried to get rid of the loop in using list comprehension, but I am too new to python to get this done. Can anyone give me a hint for nested list comprehension shortening this code further down?

Thank you for your audience.

Comment: In the list of answers to [Generate Pascal's triangle](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3815/generate-pascals-triangle) you may find additional ideas.

Comment: The shortest solution I know of is 68 bytes, which would have scored a 8.3. But apparently a [63 byte solution](http://codegolf.com/competition/leaderboard/pascals-triangle/python) exists.

Comment: There's a 63-byte Python solution in the duplicate thread, *but* that's taking input from stdin, so hard-coding 31 would save 5 for a score of 8.55.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The only problem with that solution, is that you'd need to replace `print x` with `print' '.join(map(str,x))` for a loss of 18 bytes.

Comment: @primo, ok. Still, using that with the [even better Python answer there](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3960/194) (oh, I see it's yours) equals the 8.25 best score in python2.

Comment: Interesting. I must have posted that before I registered. That could have been made a byte shorter, actually: `a=[];exec"a=map(sum,zip(a,[0]+a))+[1];print a;"*input()`

Comment: Having seem [this thread on the mother meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174045/is-stack-overflow-killing-itself-by-parental-control) I know this is not going to be what you want to hear, but ... with the very limited exception of the "Tip" series of questions ([python version](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54/)) we don't actually answer "Help me to golf this particular code" questions here. We pose open challenges and compete on the answers. And, yeah, that's a little different from most Stack Exchange sites, But in any case, welcome. Please stay around.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit shorter, but still no good:

```python
l=[1]
while(len(l)<32):
 print' '.join(map(str,l))
 l=[1]+map(int.__add__,l,l[1:]+[0])
```

And this one comes in at a score of 8.28 (credit to @primo):

```python
l=[1];exec"print' '.join(map(str,l));l=map(sum,zip([0]+l,l+[0]));"*31
```

Comment: Thank you, I learned a lot. Replacing the loop with a exec"..;"*count will server for future challenges.
Also I like your int.__add__ in replacement of lambda x,y:x+y

Comment: I like to say sorry not looking at the duplicate thread. I posted this one at stackoverflow and they recomended this site. So I posted it again, but forgot to do a thorough search.
Thank you for your answers.