# Evaluate the binomial theorem!

Tags: code-golf, math

Your mission, even if you don't accept it, is to input three numbers from STDIN or file:

> 5 0.5 6

What you must do is evaluate this:

> (5a + 0.5b)^6

This basically means that the first two numbers are the coefficients of a and b and the third is the exponent in a binomial expansion.

Rules:

- The first two numbers are either integers or simple terminating fractions.
- The third number is a positive integer.
- Do not use any inbuilt binomial functions from libs. (thanks to comments)
- The shortest code wins!

Go on, do it.

Comment: The interesting part of this has already been done as [Generate Pascal's triangle](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3815/generate-pascals-triangle)

Comment: What's the objective winning criteria?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: not necessarily, for example the APL-like languages have binomials built in (as `!` at least in APL and J). Indeed, the winner of that question used J's `!`. It would certainly have been longer if he had to hand-code it, and assuming that this question does not allow their use.

Comment: @GigaWatt: I'm assuming shortest code wins, since it's tagged as code-golf.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

#### C (C99), 223 chars

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int f(int n,int k){
    return k==0?1:(n*f(n-1,k-1))/k;
}
int main(void){
    float a,b;int n;
    scanf("%f%f%d",&a,&b,&n);
    for(int k=0;k<=n;k++)
        printf("%d*(%fa)^%d*(%fb)^%d+",f(n,k),a,n-k,b,k);
    puts("0");
}
```

Input:

```
1 1 2
```

Output:

```
1*(1.000000a)^2*(1.000000b)^0+2*(1.000000a)^1*(1.000000b)^1+1*(1.000000a)^0*(1.000000b)^2+0
```

Comment: Do you have check if `k==0`? I think a simple `k` would do the same.

Comment: My brief attempt at optimization: http://ideone.com/tUlfKs

Comment: @GigaWatt: Well, it wouldn't be C99 then.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica 36

```
InputForm@Expand[(#1 a + #2 b )^#3] &
```

Usage

```
InputForm@Expand[(#1 a + #2 b )^#3] &[5, .5, 6]
```

Result:

```
15625*a^6 +9375.*a^5*b +2343.75*a^4*b^2 +312.5*a^3*b^3 +23.4375*a^2*b^4 + 0.9375*a*b^5 + 0.015625*b^6
```

Answer (score 0):

F# 153 chars 156 bytes

```
let a,b,n=1.,2.,3
let rec C k=if k=0 then 1 else (n-k+1)*C(k-1)/k
List.iter(fun i->printf"%+ga^%ib^%i"(pown a (n-i)*pown b i*float(C i)) (n-i) i)[0..n]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 144 bytes

```python
a,b,n=input();f=lambda n:-~(n and~-n*f(~-n))
for k in range(-~n):print"+ "[0**k]+"%d*(%d*a^%d)*(%d*b^%d)"%(f(n)/f(k)/f(n-k),a**(n-k),n-k,b**k,k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBCsIwEEX3nmIIFGbSBLXLSk8iChNiNESnJdSFm1w9pgr/Pd7mL5/1MctQKxtnZIqyvFekU5ie/HKeQUZbUIDFFys6YDPRLswZEkSBzHK/oS1C45KjrKoHdT5onS696rzGBl87T79yW6kOAwrtA6ZNYhMZ1vofTca1t0lU69FA2/AF)