# Kolmogorov-simple numbers

Tags: number, code-challenge, kolmogorov-complexity, open-ended-function

If you visit Code Golf often, you may have heard of [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity). It's usually defined as the amount of bytes required to express some string in a programming language.

Here the Kolmogorov-complexity of a natural number is defined similarly: the number of bytes required to represent it in a programming language.

A number is Kolmogorov-simple if it's **more** space-efficient to represent it with the programming language, then with simply storing it in binary (base-256). In other words, if \$b\$ is the Kolmogorov-complexity of a number \$n\$, \$n\$ is Kolmogorov-simple iff \$b\lt\log_{256}(n+1)\$. Every Turing-complete language has infinitely many Kolmogorov-simple numbers.

Your task is to find the smallest Kolmogorov-simple number. In other words, output the smallest number \$n\$ in \$b\$ bytes, such that \$b<\log_{256}(n+1)\$.

### Rules

- If you express the number \$n\$, your program has to be at most \$\lceil \log_{256}(n+1)\rceil-1\$ bytes long.
- The number has to be a positive whole number
- Use a **reasonable** IO format. These *may* include: printing to stdout, expressions, functions, storing the number to a variable, pushing the number to stack or taking a number as input and comparing it the represented number. Try to stick to the [convention](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422). Floating point numbers, complex numbers and fractions are allowed, as long as it's **exactly** an integer.
- If you use a text-based format, your output should match this regex: `((\d+(\.\d*)?)|(\d*\.\d+))(e[+-]?\d+)?`. That is, it should be a decimal number. Trailing newlines etc. are allowed.

Smallest number outputted (i.e. the value \$n\$) per language wins!

Comment: To clarify, the winning criterion is smallest number? If so, this should be tagged [tag:code-challenge], since [tag:code-golf] is strictly for when the winning criterion is just "shortest code".

Comment: Since caird's Retina answer can't be beaten, maybe you should make this "smallest number per language wins"

Comment: @tjjfvi isn't this basically how all code-golf challenges (implicitly) work? Otherwise why would anyone golf in a language other than Jelly, Osabie, etc.

Comment: @AnttiP Yeah, but this isn't [tag:code-golf] so explicit mention in the OP might help counteract "oh, 1 can't be beaten, guess I'll find another challenge" (which seems especially likely when a nigh-unbeatable answer is accepted)

Comment: Related: [What is the smallest positive base 10 integer that can be printed by a program shorter (in characters) than itself?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67921/39242)

Comment: @AnttiP - surely accepting an answer (especially <2h after posting the challenge) contradicts the "smallest number **per language** wins" scoring...?

Comment: What do you mean by _expressions_ as an allowed I/O format? Does that mean that we can _return_ something like `"2**9"` or that the code snippet `2**9` is allowed? (in which case it would not really be about I/O but about the format of the answer itself).

Comment: @Arnauld originally I intended for simple expressions to be valid (like code snippets, not literal outputs like `"2**9"`), but since it seems that those are not generally accepted, even for kolmogorov-complexity questions, and most answers already include IO, they are now not valid (sorry @tjjfvi).

Comment: IMO allowing snippets for this challenge makes sense, as it’s about the size of the number, not the size of the code. By forcing IO requirements to be included, it’s no longer about “the smallest number that can be generated more compactly than its size in bytes”, but about “the smallest number that can be generated and printed more compactly than its size in bytes”. The latter, IMO, is a lot less interesting and seems less in the spirit of the challenge.

Comment: @tjjfvi I agree that it would be the most natural or correct thing to do, but since for most languages where it matters, the polyglot `2e7` is quite unbeatable, it makes the challenge slightly less interesting IMO.

Comment: Doesn't `ceil(log256(n+1))-1` equal `floor(log256(n))`?

Comment: Could you clarify whether the inequality is strict or not, as "at most" vs "\$b < \log_{256}(n+1)\$" contradict each other?

Comment: @caird_coinheringaahing The inequality is strict, and there is no contradiction. If there is, find some \$n\$ where they contradict.

Answer (score 10):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 0 bytes, outputs `1`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPwPBAA)

Outputs `1`, and \$\log_{256} 2 = 0.125 > 0\$

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte, outputs `256`

```
⁹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R487//wE)

This outputs `256` in one byte, and \$\log_{256} (257) \approx 1.0007 > 1\$

Comment: Well, guess that's as good as it gets, huh :P

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Unless you can find a language where the empty program outputs a number between 1 and 255, it can't be beaten

Comment: (something something MetaGolfScript)

Comment: How is `⁹` 1 byte?? Looks like 3 to me. Jelly clearly specifies the encoding at UTF-8 and I'm not even aware of encodings that offer this character in a 1-byte form.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Jelly uses a [custom code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page) to display its commands, so that they aren't just the random characters shown as UTF-8. `⁹` is byte `0x89` in hex, so I could encode this program as ``, but its a lot nicer to use Jelly's code page instead

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) (& likely polyglot), 3 bytes, outputs 16777216 = 256\$^3\$

```r
8^8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/3yLO4v9/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [1+](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/209529), 20 bytes, outputs \$2^{160}\$

*Reduced from \$2^{2^8}\$ due to @null*

```
11+"*"*"+"*"*"*"*"*:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVVLb5tAEL7zKybkAMQYgxMlDQ2XHCr1YlVWeiIUrWFtUIGlu@smUdvf7s6CscEOao2F9vHNN@@hfpMZq64/1Hy3u4RMylr4s9kmF9LZ5DLbrpyElbMvhCfF2/SJvNJi5q6Se5re3SXz9e2auvSGJvd3t@m1N/fo9Y1LtLysGZcg3oS25qyEhBUFTWTOKgH7u5T@2FJNEzaIFIJ2a1o2/PqjaSldA6toXWyFKRAbwAK3lq8B/vI1VAy5uWz3@7OCVibqcwjf/LTgIoD58Vr9ap5X0tS/CrKhPugwgQ4duhHudAjXeUFBMlhRoK802UqaRro1YFEy9DWXpnc8z6saLWR1z4DQi2wwuHEEcfKCIIQ6nJLUHEg7ScEE3Z/RQqB9LRx9bM6aV1basLRhJaQNjzYs8D6MVLzsY/Bc/DfgNeOQILciGoQpgSAAwzSGwXmESQDe4Aj1OKRGp1JzYZ0zWGcM01OGZag4alabVqRSOLhEokd4AHfI0kvU53JFClIlNIUVJ8l3KsXFSTIGCZm/Y@SlAaRKURFuXB8j@I5Hi6PrjU0XQd@o/zPm1IjmtbAhKVXtYlI@Ecxqc/qSqSJboOuqYDE71lEZU3WER@Ei6vuiqh2Z/NP4KTg66Rk@iM4xzxpBTfoo0WZF9UC7GpO6ek/q6l9S@kAqnHrRGHLWIDmTRNJx25@f@7DpKO5bA6OvUukN90banbWjRjz0zXXVRefpw2GluhJGFV8ig@rHrOy0RiNIp6@LrISpygtHwFaaRrUtV5T72FvWaGjtvjzjaSebZATrUrbiONBGCXwkaIv6EB@kCnR9TOCj0oj1LWTKttJ54TnmIMl4Jz@qKUTBtgGe@JaOgE4HUTMqZdX1AVao5y@xHyKnJlzm6gtiGr@N8zmAlCiHcxetTUO1dCM1ddRqHp3BD1@XA/acUmV02e/FZjSPOBIdvD32em@8aIiM44qUNI4VXo/jkuRVHOstYWePtdt53kS/wqd9N4@/c5o8O@j/Xw)

The fastest way to get big numbers in 1+ (of which I am its creator) is to repeatedly square. \$\lceil\log_{256}(2^{160}+1)\rceil-1=20\$.

Comment: `11+1+"*"*"*"*"*"*"*:` is smaller.

Comment: `11+"*"*"+"*"*"*"*"*:` is smaller.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 38 bytes, outputs ≈2³⁰⁴

```
@for /l %%a in (1,1,92)do @cmd/cset/a3
```

`log₂₅₆(33...33) ≈ 38.004`

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 24 bytes, outputs (10<sup>63</sup>-1)/3

```
+[+++++>+<]++++[++++>.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO1obBOy0bWJBNJhnp2cT@/8/AA)

This creates 51, the ASCII value of `3`, as 255/5, and then outputs it 63=252/4 times.

`+[+++++>+>+<<]>[->.<]` falls just short of working: in 21 bytes, it outputs `3` 51 times for ≈3.33×10<sup>50</sup>, while 256<sup>21</sup>≈3.74×10<sup>50</sup>.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `H`, 0 bytes

The `H` flag pre-sets the stack to 100.

$$log_{256}\;101 =  0.83227643534397 > 0$$

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=H&code=&inputs=&header=&footer=)

For a program without flags, you can use `₈` to output 256, similar to
[caird coinheringaahing's Jelly answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239759/45220)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), 8 bytes, `27368747340080914432`

(displayed as `27368747340080914000`)

```javascript
_=>7**23
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1s5cS8vI@H9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqbmfwA)

The actual value of \$7^{23}\$ is \$27368747340080916343\$ but we get \$27368747340080914432\$ because of IEEE-754 loss of precision.

We have \$\log_{256}(27368747340080914432+1)\approx 8.07\$

Comment: Looks like not just loss of precision but also inaccurate conversion to decimal... :-( Values resulting from loss of precision should never end in 0s.

Comment: And an interesting question is whether the number here is actually 27368747340080914432 (the value the program produces) or 27368747340080914000 (the value shown if you print that number as a decimal string in js).

Comment: I believe this is 27368747340080914432. It may be verified by `BigInt(7**23)`

Comment: I've updated it to the internal value. My guess is that there's an intermediate conversion to `2.7368747340080914e+19` ([like Python does](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew1zPQEvLyFjPQPP/fwA)) before eventually displaying it without the scientific notation.

Comment: Don't `_=>8e16` work?

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 3 bytes, outputs `16777216`

```
8⋆8
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=eCDihpAgOOKLhjgKeOKLiDI1NuKLhuKBvDEreA==)

$$\log_{256}\left(8^8+1\right) > \log_{256}\left(8^8\right) = 3$$

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes, outputs 9! = 362880 = 256^2.3

```
Π9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9wCy///AQ)

Comment: `Π9` is 3 bytes, not 2.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Husk uses a custom codepage, so while it is 3 bytes when encoded in UTF-8 in Husk's custom code page it's 2 bytes.  It's just displayed this way for the convenience of the reader.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE - [here](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Codepage) is the Husk codepage of 256 characters

Comment: Ah, TIL inventing different character encodings to cheat at golf is standard practice for golf langs...

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE it isn't cheating, the alternative would be to have a bunch of unreadable junk chars. The bytes are the same, this is just way easier to read.

Comment: @thejonymyster: My alternative would be that you're only allowed to count 127 (or really only 97 or so - printable ones and nl/tab) characters as single-byte, and have to count the rest as 2- or 3-byte.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE a byte is a byte, it doesn't have to correspond to any character encoding at all, we could just type raw bits into a file, it's just much less convenient than allowing character encodings for readability. No unfair advantage is gained by giving a custom set of symbols to each byte

Answer (score 2):

## x86-64 machine code, 7 bytes, outputs \$2^{56}\$

```
6A 01 58 48 0F C8 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDLasMwEDxbX7FVMEjNg/RBD0ndS8699FRocpBlyRbIkrFsImPy63XXfYRelh1mdmZY2TTrUsppEqEGBm@UkU1pfS4saKJ3SdOHCu5I0vgGWhFJkoez@F1b1RFOge@Jip1qHdADhbF3wZROFWC9K3@GcR1oxvcXQhbGSdsXCp5DVxi/qV4ImelaGMc4GTGpRawZTRfWxqOjq/kUM67E0b0KWRmnQPpC7ejMzRYRMtiuYEBYeBj/5JBu79/RZcgYu3aTlWhvueYfcbk8YTE4V8YqYAPcoEk8PPwPBJYayIdOBf7dJyJ5maZPqa0ow7Sunx5x4AMz1Cv7BQ)

Returns a value in RAX, as is standard.

In assembly:

```
.global f
f:  push 1      # (2 bytes) Push 1 onto the stack.
    pop rax     # (1 byte)  Pop it out into RAX.
    bswap rax   # (3 bytes) Reverse the order of the bytes in RAX.
    ret         # (1 byte)  Return.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 3 bytes, outputs `100000000`

```
8|A
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=8%7CA&i=&m=2)

$$\left \lceil{\log_{256}\left(10^8+1\right)}\right\rceil - 1= 3$$

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 11 bytes, outputs `5704427701027032306735164424192`

```python
print 9<<99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EwdLGxtLy/38A)

$$\log_{256}(5704427701027032306735164424192+1)-1 = 11.77$$

Comment: `5**38` would give a smaller number (with a log256 of 11.029).

Comment: `4**44` is even better with `log(4**44)= 11` so `log(4**44+1)>11`

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 3 bytes, outputs `22222222`.

```
×⁸2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCMkMze1WMNCR0HJSElT0/r///@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. `log₂₅₆(22222222) ≈ 3.05` Explanation: Charcoal only prints strings by default, so something like `φ` (`Print(f);`) prints 1000 `-`s instead of `1000`; casting to string costs a byte, meaning we now need a value of at least `65536`, however no predefined variable now holds a suitable value. This means we now need to look for a 3-byte answer that prints at least `16777216`, which can most easily be achieved in a number of ways by repeating the character `2`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 13 bytes, outputs `20282409603651670423947251286016`

```python
print(16**26)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew9BMS8vITPP/fwA)

From what I can understand, this is the *absolute minimum* for a 13 byte program - it prints 256**13, the minimum number that needs 13 bytes to store. Good luck getting anything below this in Python 3.

Bonuses I found:

```python
print(18**25) # 19% bigger than the actual answer
```

```python
print(27**22) # 52% bigger than the actual answer
```

```python
print(15**27) # 2.8x as big as the actual answer
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 5 bytes, outputs 256<sup>5</sup> = 4<sup>20</sup> = `1099511627776`

```
4 20?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/30TByMD@/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 12 bytes, outputs `79228162514264337593543950336`

```python
print(4**48)
```

Inspired by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242352/112488) answer.

Explanation:

```python
4**48 == 16**24 == 256**12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew0RLy8RC8/9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), 7 bytes, outputs `150094635296999121`

```ruby
p 3**36
```

Similar to other answers, uses `p` to debug print the number. Fortunately for numbers the debug print value is the same as the normal output would be.

$$\left \lceil{\log_{256}\left(3^{36}+1\right)}\right\rceil - 1= 7$$

Answer (score 0):

## [Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/excel), 5 bytes, outputs `1,09951E+21` ≈ 2<sup>40</sup> = 256<sup>5</sup>

```
=2^40
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL, 2 bytes

```
!9
```

The program prints factorial of 9 = 362880. Validation of allowed length:

```
      1-⍨⌈256⍟1+!9
2
```